# PCRE error compiling Apache httpd 2.4.18 on RHEL 5.11

Tags: apache, pcre

Initial attempt of configure gave this error:

```
checking for pcre-config... false
configure: error: pcre-config for libpcre not found. PCRE is required and available from http://pcre.org/
```

I installed pcre-devel:

```
yum install pcre-devel.x86_64
```

Now configure is successful.  However, make gives this err:

```
util_pcre.c: In function 'ap_regcomp':
util_pcre.c:128: error: 'PCRE_DUPNAMES' undeclared (first use in this function)
util_pcre.c:128: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
util_pcre.c:128: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [util_pcre.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/downloads/httpd-2.4.18/server'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/downloads/httpd-2.4.18/server'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Looking for help to resolve make pcre problem.

Comment: please use latest pcre. pcre package in repo is too old for apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Was able to install Apache httpd-2.4.17 successfully using the same configure and make as httpd-2.4.18.